# undefined method `perform' for nil:NilClass

Tags: sass, font-awesome

I'm trying to update font-awesome to last release using .scss.

When i try to compile using campass it throws this error:

```
 >>> Change detected at 17:51:13 to: ui/_font_awesome.scss
NoMethodError on line ["323"] of /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.0.alpha.64/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb: undefined method `perform' for nil:NilClass
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.0.alpha.64/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:321:in `map'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.0.alpha.64/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:321:in `run_interp_no_strip'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.0.alpha.64/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:331:in `run_interp'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.0.alpha.64/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:295:in `visit_directive'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.0.alpha.64/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `visit'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.0.alpha.64/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:20:in `visit'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.0.alpha.64/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:146:in `block in visit_import'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.0.alpha.64/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:146:in `map'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.0.alpha.64/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:146:in `visit_import'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.0.alpha.64/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `visit'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.0.alpha.64/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:20:in `visit'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.0.alpha.64/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:146:in `block in visit_import'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.0.alpha.64/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:146:in `map'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.0.alpha.64/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:146:in `visit_import'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.0.alpha.64/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `visit'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.0.alpha.64/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:20:in `visit'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.0.alpha.64/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `block in visit_children'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.0.alpha.64/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `map'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.0.alpha.64/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `visit_children'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.0.alpha.64/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:29:in `block in visit_children'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.0.alpha.64/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:41:in `with_environment'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.0.alpha.64/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:28:in `visit_children'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.0.alpha.64/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `block in visit'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.0.alpha.64/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:49:in `visit_root'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.0.alpha.64/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `visit'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.0.alpha.64/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:20:in `visit'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.0.alpha.64/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:7:in `visit'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.0.alpha.64/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:20:in `render'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.0.alpha.64/lib/sass/engine.rb:305:in `_render'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.0.alpha.64/lib/sass/engine.rb:252:in `render'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.1/lib/compass/compiler.rb:140:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.1/lib/compass/compiler.rb:126:in `timed'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.1/lib/compass/compiler.rb:139:in `block in compile'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.1/lib/compass/logger.rb:45:in `red'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.1/lib/compass/compiler.rb:138:in `compile'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.1/lib/compass/compiler.rb:118:in `compile_if_required'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.1/lib/compass/compiler.rb:103:in `block (2 levels) in run'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.1/lib/compass/compiler.rb:101:in `each'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.1/lib/compass/compiler.rb:101:in `block in run'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.1/lib/compass/compiler.rb:126:in `timed'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.1/lib/compass/compiler.rb:100:in `run'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.1/lib/compass/commands/watch_project.rb:147:in `recompile'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fssm-0.2.8.1/lib/fssm/path.rb:73:in `call'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fssm-0.2.8.1/lib/fssm/path.rb:73:in `run_callback'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fssm-0.2.8.1/lib/fssm/path.rb:55:in `callback_action'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fssm-0.2.8.1/lib/fssm/path.rb:35:in `update'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fssm-0.2.8.1/lib/fssm/state/directory.rb:39:in `block in modified'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fssm-0.2.8.1/lib/fssm/state/directory.rb:37:in `each'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fssm-0.2.8.1/lib/fssm/state/directory.rb:37:in `modified'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fssm-0.2.8.1/lib/fssm/state/directory.rb:18:in `refresh'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fssm-0.2.8.1/lib/fssm/backends/inotify.rb:12:in `block in add_handler'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rb-inotify-0.8.8/lib/rb-inotify/notifier.rb:200:in `call'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rb-inotify-0.8.8/lib/rb-inotify/notifier.rb:200:in `block in watch'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rb-inotify-0.8.8/lib/rb-inotify/watcher.rb:41:in `[]'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rb-inotify-0.8.8/lib/rb-inotify/watcher.rb:41:in `callback!'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rb-inotify-0.8.8/lib/rb-inotify/event.rb:128:in `callback!'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rb-inotify-0.8.8/lib/rb-inotify/notifier.rb:233:in `block in process'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rb-inotify-0.8.8/lib/rb-inotify/notifier.rb:233:in `each'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rb-inotify-0.8.8/lib/rb-inotify/notifier.rb:233:in `process'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rb-inotify-0.8.8/lib/rb-inotify/notifier.rb:216:in `run'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fssm-0.2.8.1/lib/fssm/backends/inotify.rb:20:in `run'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fssm-0.2.8.1/lib/fssm/monitor.rb:26:in `run'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fssm-0.2.8.1/lib/fssm.rb:70:in `monitor'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.1/lib/compass/commands/watch_project.rb:87:in `perform'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.1/lib/compass/commands/base.rb:18:in `execute'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.1/lib/compass/commands/project_base.rb:19:in `execute'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.1/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:43:in `perform!'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.1/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:15:in `run!'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.1/bin/compass:29:in `block in <top (required)>'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.1/bin/compass:43:in `call'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.1/bin/compass:43:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/local/bin/compass:19:in `load'
  /usr/local/bin/compass:19:in `<main>'
```

I've spent all afternoon searching to find someone with same problem but didn't find anything...

Any guess about what could be the problem?

Ty!

Answer (score 1):

Check any directives you have added to your sass files recently (`@include`, `@import`, `@extend`) and verify that there are no typos.

You may get this error when sass tries to execute a directive it does not recognize.
eg. say you typed `@includ` when you meant `@include`